# C# Http request with client certificates returns 500

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am trying to send a rest call by passing client certificate to the HttpClientHandler but I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error back:

```
var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile("C:\\work\\certs\\pwm-acc.pem", "C:\\work\\certs\\pwm-acc.key");
using var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Clear();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

_httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://pwm.intranet/ServiceCert/api/")
};

var restOfUrl = $"Accounts?AppID={AppId}";
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, restOfUrl);

try
{
    using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<AIMResponse>(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    return result;
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
    _logger.LogDebug(ex, "API request failed.", request);
    throw;
}
```

The response I am getting is:
`Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).`

The response content contains a HTML error page:

```
<b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
 <br><br>
 <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>
```

The same API call, but using curl works:

`curl --cert /etc/pki/tls/certs/pwm-acc.pem --key /etc/pki/tls/certs/pwm-acc.key "https://pwm.intranet/ServiceCert/api/Accounts?AppID=DUMMYID" --verbose`

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Expires: -1
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552001; includeSubDomains; preload
< Date: Tue, 04 Jan 2022 17:37:44 GMT
< Content-Length: 503
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, a 500 is usually an error on the server's end, so maybe it's a bug over there? By the way, your curl command line doesn't use the same paths as the C# code, are those the same files?

Comment: I know a 500 means something went wrong on the server, but why does it works using curl and fails with c# code?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel yes, those are the same certificates, but on different machines.

Comment: What's in the response's body? Is there some sort of error message that could explain things?

Comment: I am getting a HTML error response, updated the post with it.

Comment: There are lots of reasons for this error and there is not enough info to give a single solution.  The TLS encryption is probably failing.  One reason for TLS failing is the encryption mode is different.  One common reason for the encryption mode to fail is the padding mode.  c# and java uses different defaults for padding.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in the html result, ie enable the remote error reporting? Is the certificate self-signed or rooted at commonly known CA? Does it contain the full cert-chain or just the leaf-certificate?

Comment: @derpirscher I cannot access the server logs. The certificate is signed by a known enterprise CA.